# Javascript backtrace

Tags: javascript, reflection, callstack, backtrace

How to I get a backtrace in Javascript?

Ideal features:

- entry function name, or some meaningful identifier for anonymous functions,
- argument list at each level,
- line numbers.

Can this be done in standard ECMAScript?

If not, can it be done in the common web browser dialects?

Thanks.

### Edit --

Thanks for your suggestions.

My dialect doesnot support `arguments.caller` or `arguments.callee`.

I can do this:

```
try {
    let x = null;
    x .foo ();
}
catch (e) {
        debug (dump (e.stack));
}
```

Which gets me the information as a string, which is okay for at-a-glance, but it would be a great help to walk `e.stack`. Does it have a standard form?

Thanks again.

Comment: The best way to get strack traces is to use browser based debuggers.

Comment: What is your dialect ? What is `dump` ?

Comment: It's a proprietry dialect, seems mostly complete, has a few extentions.

Answer (score 41):

In my debugging experience, I always use this

```
(function () { console.log(new Error().stack); })();
```

As the comments below suggested, the readers should prefer:

```
console.log(new Error().stack);
```

Comment: Why the extra function wrapper? can't you just use `console.log(new Error().stack);`? It worked for me.

Comment: I don't see any reason for the wrapper function either

Comment: I like clean global scope. So I add a wrapper.

Comment: Adding the wrapper function obviously adds an extra function (pointlessly?) to top of the stack, making the code you care about one step down. I recommend readers don't do this, idk if the poster had a reason for wanting it this way so I won't change the answer.

Answer (score 10):

Another way is to use
`console.trace();`

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/trace

Answer (score 3):

This lib: [stacktrace-js](https://www.stacktracejs.com/) works anywhere, not only with errors.

Example:

```
StackTrace.get()
    .then(stack => { console.log(stack) })
    .catch(err => { console.log(err) });
```